# UPS for HP ProLiant DL180 G6

Tags: hardware, hp, ups

I inherited HP ProLiant DL180 G6 model supposed TB used for some additional (non mission-critical) work and need to buy the UPS for it. I've read that PSUs for HP servers tolerate pretty much only the pure sinusoid-wave power supply (not the simulated-sinusoid one), I hope someone here can verify that.

However, the main question is, what output power should UPS be able to provide on battery power? The PSU bears the label `460W`, which probably indicates maximum output power of the power supply, is that correct?

In that case, 600W output power UPS should be sufficient, but can people here verify the peak power consumption of that server they've seen (if anybody's still using such old hardware, obviously).

Comment: There is usually a label on the power supply specifying numbers for both input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Used those types of servers in the past, and yes you want a pure sinewave UPS. Using anything less than that will likely cause a cold reboot of the server in the event of any kind of power blip or just lock up entirely.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I simply measured it myself with the device you plug into socket that shows current power consumption in watts. Results for HP ProLiant DL180 G6, host OS Debian 9.6:

```
130W       - boot
290W       - loadavg 1400+, stress-ng --aggressive -a 0 -class cpu,filesystem
190-260W   - reboot
115W-125W  - no VMs running, just host OS
130W-160W  - 1 Debian 9.6 VM running
180W-200W  - 9 VMs booting, 8 VMs are Debian 9.6, 1 VM is Windows 7
140W-165W  - 9 VMs running, 1m loadavg varying from 1 to 3.6
```